# why paypal sandbox testing UI has no direct credit card payment method?

Tags: user-interface, paypal, sandbox

Paypal claims that customers without paypal accounts could pay with their credit cards directly, and it looks like true with the real paypal account payment interface like this:

[image]

however, when I tested with their sandbox interface, the interface looks like:

[image]

it seems like the sandbox testing environment has not been upgraded yet? Or we could trust that the IPN etc.. will work the same as the new credit card processing etc..?

Comment: How about that link on the left, "Don't have a PayPal account? // Use your credit card or bank account (where available)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the GUI isn't the same.  But it looks like the functionality is there; you click the Continue button on the left.

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice it. Now, do you know how to get a testing visa, mastercard for paypal sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

just the GUI change , it was an old bug at Paypal of page versions but they say its fixed now.. hopefully u don't have to face this issue now